# Airflow DAG parallel task delay/latency in execution by 60 seconds

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

We have moved to **AirFlow 1.10.2** to resolve the CPU usage, Good thing is that the issue we had, got fixed in our environment. However, we have observed that the DAG's tasks though are getting submitted and shows running on the AirFlow dashboard, but they kind of hold up with actual processing and then appears to remain in the queue for about 60 seconds after that the actual execution happens. Please note that for our use case implementation

- The AirFlow DAGs are not time dependent i.e. they are not **'**Scheduled DAGs**'** but are triggered via a python code.
- AirFlow v1.10.2 is being used as a single standalone instalation [`executor = LocalExecutor`] .

The python code watches a directory for any file(s) that arrive. For any file, it observes, the code triggers the AirFlow DAG. We get bundles of files arriving and so at any given instance, we have scenarios where multiple instance of the same DAGs are getting invoked [ *code snippet provided below* ]. The DAGs are triggered which in turn has a task that calls a python code to trigger a Kubernetes pod where some file related processing happens. Please find below an excerpt from the DAG code

```
positional_to_ascii = BashOperator(
                    task_id="uncompress_the_file",
                    bash_command='python3.6 ' + os.path.join(cons.CODE_REPO, 'app/Code/k8Job/create_kubernetes_job.py') + ' POS-PREPROCESSING {{ dag_run.conf["inputfilepath"] }} {{ dag_run.conf["frt_id"]}}',
                    execution_timeout=None,
                    dag=dag)
```

Once this task completes it triggers another DAGs are triggered which has task that processes data from the output of the previous DAG.

Please find below a few details of our config file parameters which may assist in assessing the root cause.

```
min_file_process_interval = 60 
dag_dir_list_interval = 300 
max_threads = 2
dag_concurrency = 16
worker_concurrency = 16
max_active_runs_per_dag = 16
parallelism = 32
sql_alchemy_conn = mysql://airflow:fewfw324$gG@someXserver:3306/airflow
executor = LocalExecutor
```

The DagBag parsing time: 1.305286. Please as well find below the snapshot of the command `airflow list_dags -r` below

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
DagBag loading stats for /root/airflow/dags
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of DAGs: 7
Total task number: 23
DagBag parsing time: 1.305286
------------------------------+----------+---------+----------+------------------------------
file                          | duration | dag_num | task_num | dags
------------------------------+----------+---------+----------+------------------------------
/trigger_cleansing.py         | 0.876388 |       1 |        5 | ['trigger_cleansing']
/processing_ebcdic_trigger.py | 0.383038 |       1 |        1 | ['processing_ebcdic_trigger']
/prep_preprocess_dag.py       | 0.015474 |       1 |        6 | ['prep_preprocess_dag']
/prep_scale_dag.py            | 0.012098 |       1 |        6 | ['dataprep_scale_dag']
/mvp.py                       | 0.010832 |       1 |        2 | ['dg_a']
/prep_uncompress_dag.py       | 0.004142 |       1 |        2 | ['dataprep_unzip_decrypt_dag']
/prep_positional_trigger.py   | 0.003314 |       1 |        1 | ['prep_positional_trigger']
------------------------------+----------+---------+----------+------------------------------
```

Below is the status of the airflow-scheduler service which is showing multiple processes

```
systemctl status airflow-scheduler
● airflow-scheduler.service - Airflow scheduler daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/airflow-scheduler.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-03-09 04:44:29 EST; 33min ago
 Main PID: 37409 (airflow)
   CGroup: /system.slice/airflow-scheduler.service
           ├─37409 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37684 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37685 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37686 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37687 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37688 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37689 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37690 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37691 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37692 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37693 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37694 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37695 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37696 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37697 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37699 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37700 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37701 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37702 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37703 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37704 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37705 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37706 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37707 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37708 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37709 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37710 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37712 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37713 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37714 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37715 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37717 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           ├─37718 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
           └─37722 /usr/bin/python3.6 /bin/airflow scheduler
```

Now the fact that we have several files comming in the DAGs are constantly being fired and have ample DAG task that gets into a waiting stage. Strangely we though didnt have this issue when we were using v1.9 please advise.

Comment: `..The python code watches a directory for any file(s) that arrive. For any file, it observes, the code triggers the AirFlow DAG...`. This appears to be a perfect candidate for using [`FileSensor`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/sensors/file_sensor.py). Regarding `FileSensor`, the [docs](https://incubator-airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code.html#airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor.FileSensor) say `"Waits for a file or folder to land in a filesystem."`. The downside of `sensor`s is that they occupy an  *execution slot* in worker doing nothing but waiting.

Comment: @y2k-shubham well in 1.10.2 sensors get scheduled to a worker for each poke. So they don't ALWAYS use a worker slot to wait.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that in the '**airflow.cfg**' file , the value of the 'min_file_process_interval' was 60. Setting that to zero resolved the problem I reported here.